# I have created a script in selenium for odoo framework in python , so can I use it for a load testing ? if yes then how?

Tags: python, selenium, load-testing, odoo

I have created a script in selenium in odoo framework in python , now I want to test it for load testing then which tool is best ?
should I have to make another script for load testing again or I can use the same script for a load testing , if yes then how can I use it

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do performance testing with Selenium. you can use Jmeter or any other Performance/Load testing tool

Answer (score -1):

You can combine your selenium script with JMeter webdriver and then perform a load test.

Answer (score -1):

[Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) automation framework (it's free, open source and written in Python by the way) has support of Python [Selenium tests](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Selenium/) so you should be able to run them in multithreaded manner.